# ZSH tab completion - don't fill in first file

Tags: zsh

If I have files "something1" and "something2" in a folder, how do I make ZSH's tab completion fill in only the common characters? For example, I would type:

```
som<Tab>
```

and I want it to fill in with "something", not "something1".

Current zstyles:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache on
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' cache-path ~/.zsh/cache/$HOST
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt '%SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=1 _complete _ignored _approximate
zstyle -e ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors \
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt '%SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s'
zstyle ':completion:*::::' completer _expand _complete _ignored _approximate
zstyle -e ':completion:*:approximate:*' max-errors \
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' tag-order all-expansions
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes 
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%B%d%b'
zstyle ':completion:*:messages' format '%d'
zstyle ':completion:*:warnings' format 'No matches for: %d' 
zstyle ':completion:*:corrections' format '%B%d (errors: %e)%b'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-subscript-:*' tag-order indexes parameters
# zstyle ':completion:*:processes' command 'ps -au$USER'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31'
#zstyle ':completion:*:processes' command 'ps ax -o pid,s,nice,stime,args | sed "/ps/d"'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' command 'ps --forest -A -o pid,user,cmd'
zstyle ':completion:*:processes-names' command 'ps axho command' 
#zstyle ':completion:*:urls' local 'www' '/var/www/htdocs' 'public_html'
zstyle ':completion:*' hosts $(awk '/^[^#]/ {print $2 $3" "$4" "$5}' /etc/hosts | grep -v ip6- && grep "^#%" /etc/hosts | awk -F% '{print $2}') 
zstyle ':completion:*:*:(^rm):*:*files' ignored-patterns '*?.o' '*?.c~' \
zstyle ':completion:*:functions' ignored-patterns '_*'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:users' ignored-patterns \
zstyle ':completion:*:scp:*' tag-order \
zstyle ':completion:*:scp:*' group-order \
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' tag-order \
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' group-order \
zstyle '*' single-ignored show
```

Comment: What do you get if you enter `zstyle` or `grep zstyle ~/.zshrc` at the command prompt. I have `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=0` as one setting and while I don't think it has an effect on what you're asking about, I do get the behavior you're seeking.

Comment: Tried that, didn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to ~/.zshrc works for me:

```
setopt noautomenu
setopt nomenucomplete
```

https://serverfault.com/a/447549

Answer (score 1):

remove line:

```
setopt menu_completion
```

from your .zshrc

and it should work fine with filling unambiguous part first.

Answer (score 0):

It works like that out of the box if you use [Zsh's new completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System). Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file (or to try it out, just paste it into the command line):

```sh
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
bindkey '^I' complete-word
```

After this, if you have two files `something1` and `something2` in your present working dir, and you type

```sh
% file s
```

and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will complete to

```sh
% file something
```

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and it will display

```
something1  something2
```

under the command line.

You can then keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through these two.

Answer (score 0):

In your zshrc file (at ~/.zshrc) paste this line
`zstyle ':autocomplete:*' insert-unambiguous yes`
if previously it was set to **no** it changing to the above line will work.

Answer (score -1):

Check out man zshoptions.  It's pretty well organized so that all of the completion options are in a "Completion" section.  I think that the option you're looking for is list_ambiguous. if so, you just need to add in the line

setopt list_ambiguous

to your .zshrc

Answer (score -1):

Good news: this is totally doable, and you won't need to worry about zstyles. (I believe.) Bad news: it's a bit tricky to answer.

A great explanation of specific zsh completion options related to the problem you're trying to solve can be found in [this specific section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html#l147) of the User's Guide to zsh.

Also, you can do a 'man zshoptions' and look for completion-specific options. The answer above mentioning list_ambiguous is part of the answer, but I don't believe it addresses the whole picture. A key question you'll need to ask yourself is "What do I want to happen after I hit TAB the first time and zsh inserts only the common characters?" You can have zsh do a lot of different things on the *second* TAB press or even the third. Using various combinations of the ZSH completion options can yield a wide variety of useful results. It all depends on what you want.

Good luck!